# Seeking a Joomla! extension to improve presentation

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm pretty new to Joomla! (using verison 3.3.6) I'm an old hand at WP development.  Currently I am looking for the right way to improve an article.  This article's content is just a list of links.  The content is :

```
<p><a href="..." >Title of Link </a></p>
<p><a href="..." >Title of Link </a></p>
<p><a href="..." >Title of Link </a></p>
<p><a href="..." >Title of Link </a></p> .....
```

and so on.

I would like to change this into responsive rows of thumbnails.  I could write a bunch of HTML into the back-end editor, and add some classes to the stylesheet, but I'd prefer to learn how to leverage Joomla's existing functions and extensions.  Would someone direct me a little?

Comment: From my experience with Joomla!, creating custom extensions is a pain.  I recommend either doing it by hand or writing your own segment of code to do it for you.

Comment: Oh, pardon me. I did not mean to imply that I want to create an extension.  I am just looking for the "joomla! way " to create this kind of content.

Comment: Okay I see, you may want to edit/clarify your title and question then.

Comment: I would install weblinks if you don't have it, and just use a category list.  Are the links to internal content or to external sites? If internal, do they all follow the same pattern?

Comment: Thanks Elin, that's the kind of input I'm seeking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joomla Template Override system. Here is the article about that:
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core